# Why not store all parameters into stack from calling functions instead of using registers R0~R3 when compiling without optimizations?

Tags: c, arm

Since we have to Store all <strike>formal</strike> parameters into stack, why doesn't the compiler push them on the stack when calling functions, **instead** of storing the first 4 parameters into R0~R3?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwq9.png)

I try to understand it, but I just cannot understand it, so can you give me some helps?

Comment: **we have to Store all formal parameters into stack** Who does make you to have to do that?

Comment: Register operations can be hundreds of times faster than memory operations.

Comment: maybe you can check my compiler's result which is under O0 optimization

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** use the tag compiler-construction when you have questions about compiler output (as the tag brief notes).  It implies you understand at least some compiler theory (as did the wording 'formal parameters').  Just call them parameters in this context.

Comment: sry, i am poor in English, in the future, i will improve my gramma, thank you for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, compilers worked by passing all parameters on the stack.  When optimizations are disabled, compilers for platforms like the ARM whose documented calling convention is specified as passing arguments in registers may on function entry store registers on a stack frame so they can process the remainder of the function as though the arguments had been passed on the stack.

Note that if a compiler was generating code that would never be linked with code generated by other tools, it could simply pass all arguments on the stack.  Doing so, however, would make generated code incompatible with code generated by other compilers.  Accepting things in registers but storing them onto the stack immediately allows a compiler to be compatible with code produced by other compilers, while still using the code-generation logic associated with the "traditional" argument passing mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks supercat! I will delve deeper into your answer!

Comment: Actually, Drepper is not helpful.  http://i.imgur.com/k0t1e.png  While an L1 hit is fast, the register access run at the CPU clock.  Ie, 2-3Ghz means well under a nano-second.  Saving things to stack means you will have undetermined access times.

Comment: @artlessnoise: The 8088 was pretty much a stack machine, except with regard to registers which would in many cases be used for relatively fixed functions, and it seems to have enjoyed a reasonable amount of success.  If one uses register-qualified objects as appropriate, even gcc -O0 can sometimes produce decent code on architectures like the ARM, and adding even a simple peephole optimizer and a pass which tracks things like whether a register or portion thereof will be used could allow suitably-written source code to yield machine code comparable to higher optimization settings.

Comment: @artlessnoise: In many cases, the most profitable optimizations are also the safest and easiest to perform.  If the address of an automatic-duration object is never taken (whether a compiler knows this via the `register` qualifier, or by simple code inspection), and at some point where it is loaded the value that was stored is still in a register, omitting the store and using the value in the register without reloading is an easy optimization.  If a value is written to stack but never loaded, omitting the store is likewise safe and easy.  Those aren't the only possible optimizations...

Comment: ...a compiler may perform, but it's safe, and it offers big payoff in exchange for minimal cost and complexity.

Comment: I agree there are some machine that are stack based (but they are historical; as well there was a 'Java chip').  Anyways, it is the assertion "Store all formal parameters into stack" of the OP.  This is a comp.sci or compiler theory issue and no practical tools will adhere to this.  It is also much easier to formally verify with a stack machine.  So, I don't think your answer addressed why real CPUs /systems would have an ABI that mandated registers (because they are way faster).  Err, that was the intent of the comments.

Comment: @artlessnoise: The OP linked to machine code which started by storing onto the stack values which were received in registers, which I took as implying the question was "why not have the caller push the values onto the stack, rather than having it load values into registers *that will then get pushed onto the stack*".  C originated as a stack-based language, and implementations for platforms like the Z80 bent over backward to process code in stack-based fashion even though using static allocation for automatic objects would have been far more efficient.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The machine code is a product of comp.sci as generated by the compiler.  The OP has no idea.  Glad you are psychic. ;)

Comment: @artlessnoise: I got my start with C back in an era where stack-based calling conventions were pretty much universal.  Perhaps I could have clarified that a *minimalistic* compiler for the ARM could pass everything on the stack if compatibility with other tools weren't required, to make clear that the only advantage of passing things in such fashion would be reduced compiler complexity.  BTW, from a historical question as to why stack passing stuck around for so long, I think that's a consequence of old-style non-prototyped function calls.  On a platform like the 68000, ...

Comment: ...a register-based calling convention would pass arguments to `void foo(int i, int j, char *p)` in a different from `void bar(char *p, int i, int j)` (passing the integers in D0 and D1, and the pointer in A0 in both cases) but a compiler which saw a call `foo(0,1,0)` or `bar(0,1,0)` without having seen a prototype would have no idea whether the value 1 should go into D0 or D1.

Comment: "why not have the caller push the values onto the stack, rather than having it load values into registers that will then get pushed onto the stack" yes, this is what i mean

Comment: @artlessnoise: Based on the last comment, it seems maybe I am psychic?  >:*3  BTW, much as people like to portray stack-based storage of arguments and other automatic-duration objects as absurd, C got its reputation for speed in an era where stack-based practices were the normal way of doing things.  Funny how people ignore that aspect of language history.

Comment: @supercat, Sincere thanks! it's really hard for me to find such a historical reason.

Comment: @supercat  Yes, I used both 68k and compilers in an era where the simplicity of stacked based access allowed other features to fit in memory.  The 68k was a precursor to various  RISC chips.  The whole concept of VLIW is to let the compiler do stuff as it has the information of the source.  I think that register are a compromise and give the compiler fast memory, which SSA and other allocation techniques have solved in the last 10-20 years.  Chip speeds get press and but not compiler developers.  Look at the code historic compilers generate.  It is why we learned assembler.  Long live Forth :)

Comment: @artlessnoise: Unfortunately, evolution of the C language has been taken over by people who think that requiring that compilers generate code for `uint1 = ushort1*ushort2;` that won't arbitrarily corrupt memory if the product exceeds `INT_MAX` would pose an unacceptable drain on performance. but sometimes optimize loops in ways that make them run slower than what -O0 would produce given the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because that's the standard for 32-bit ARM in order to produce compatible binary files that can be linked together.

[Quoting from the ARM ABI itself](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst#scope):

> **3   Scope**
>
> The AAPCS defines how subroutines can be separately written, separately compiled, and separately assembled to work together. It describes a contract between a calling routine and a called routine that defines:
>
> - Obligations on the caller to create a program state in which the called routine may start to execute.
> - Obligations on the called routine to preserve the program state of the caller across the call.
> - The rights of the called routine to alter the program state of its caller.
>
> ...

[The ABI states](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst#core-registers):

> **6.1.1   Core registers**
>
> There are 16, 32-bit core (integer) registers visible to the Arm and
> Thumb instruction sets. These are labeled r0-r15 or R0-R15. ...
>
> ...
>
> The first four registers r0-r3 (a1-a4) are used to pass argument
> values into a subroutine and to return a result value from a function.
> ...

Code compiled in ways that do not meet the ABI standard would not be able to be linked with code that does.

---

Regarding "Since we have to Store all formal parameters into stack"...

No we do not have to do that.

There's no point in pushing values onto the stack **from a register** only for the called routine to **pop that value back into a register**.  Passing arguments in registers is orders of magnitude faster than forcing them out into memory only to for the first thing the called routine does is read them back in from memory, even if that value is "hot" in cache.

Stack passing is only necessary when there aren't enough registers.

Comment: Thank you for your response; it has deepened my understanding.